# What to reply when someones says “приятного аппетита”

Tags: словоупотребление, этикет

What is the correct response?

“Спасибо”?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides `"Спасибо!"`, which is the option number one, it's also used:

> `"Благодарю!"` is almost like `спасибо` but is more sublime, expresses genuine thankfulness

and of course you can wish the same after all in return to a person if [s]he is also eating at the moment,  by saying:

> `"Взаимно."` means `"it's mutual."`: can be used standalone or after `спасибо` or `благодарю`

or

> `"[И] Вам также\тоже."`: can be said standalone instead of `спасибо` or `благодарю`
>    or added after like in this example:
>
> `"Спасибо\Благодарю! Взаимно."` or `"Спасибо\Благодарю! Вам также\тоже."`

Answer (score 3):

*Спасибо* is indeed the right response.  I can't think of the corresponding idiom in English (strangely enough), but the response to French *bon appetit* is the same *merci*.

Comment: after Спасибо is correct to say приятного аппетита to the other person or there's some other word like вам тоже

Comment: @GiannisFoulidis You can certainly say _и Вам тоже_.

Comment: Aleks G, "Вам тоже" in reply to "приятного аппетита" from any service person (waiter, barista, etc) will sound silly IMO...

Comment: @Sergey Agree, but I was specifically responding to the comment about wishing it to the other person after _спасибо_.

Answer (score 1):

Some people look at that topic strongly.

Only treating person should say "приятного аппетита" entertaining to you.
Say "спасибо" in response.

[image: An eater]

What if your table companion says "приятного аппетита"?

Answer politely "и Вам/тебе приятного аппетита".

Or impolitely "своё едим" ;-)

Or humorously "буду стараться".

Answer (score 1):

> What if your table companion says "приятного аппетита"?<
>   Answer politely "и Вам/тебе приятного аппетита".<

More common answer will be "Спасибо, вам также".

> Or impolitely "своё едим" ;-)<

I'm Russian, but I've never heard such sentence - it seems that it's out of use in modern Russian.